# It sounds complex but its not, Comparing Files in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, compare

I have a folder with a huge amount of files in it with lots of different extensions (abc, abc_trg, def, def_trg, ghi, ghi_trg, jkl, mno).
You will see that there are some files that have a matching 'trigger' file, but not all files in this folder need to have a trigger file, it is just the following extensions that must have a trigger file: abc, def, ghi.

```
filename1.abc
filename1.abc_trg
filename2.def
filename2.def_trg
filename3.abc
filename4.def_trg
filename5.ghi
filename6.jkl
filename7.mno
filename8.ghi
filename8.ghi_trg
filename9.jkl
```

i.e. The extension types that do have Trigger files (abc, abc_trg, def, def_trg, ghi, ghi_trg) must have a matching filename.

I need a PowerShell script that will analyse the and compare files that are meant to exist with a trigger filetype (abc, abc_trg, def, def_trg, ghi, ghi_trg) and if a match is found (e.g. filename1, filename2, filename8) or if there are files that have extensions not in this list, e.g. jkl & mno (filename6.jkl, filename7.mno, filename9.jkl) then those files are left/not touched.

If there are files that are meant to have a matching extension & trigger file, but do not, i.e. they have become orphaned, then these need to be deleted (e.g. filename3.abc, filename4.def_trg, filename5.ghi)

So the resultant file list should look like this:

```
filename1.abc
filename1.abc_trg
filename2.def
filename2.def_trg
filename6.jkl
filename7.mno
filename8.ghi
filename8.ghi_trg
filename9.jkl
```

Here is my code so far:

```
$strDir = "D:\Temp\FileCompareTest\"

$strFileTypesToIgnore = ".jkl",".mno"
$strExtABC = ".abc"
$strExtABC_Trigger = ".abc_trg"
$strExtDEF = ".def"
$strExtDEF_Trigger = ".def_trg"
$strExtGHI = ".ghi"
$strExtGHI_Trigger = ".ghi_trg"

$arrFiles = Get-ChildItem $strDir -exclude $strFileTypesToIgnore

ForEach ($objFile in $arrFiles) {
    $strFilename = $objFile.BaseName
    $strExtension = $objFile.Extension

    If ($strExtension -eq ".abc") {
        $arrFiles2 = Get-ChildItem $strDir -exclude $strFileTypesToIgnore

        ForEach ($objFile2 in $arrFiles2) {
            $strFilename2 = $objFile2.BaseName
            $strExtension2 = $objFile2.Extension

            If ($strExtension2 -eq ".abc_trg") {
                If (Compare-Object $strFilename $strFilename2) {
                    Write-Host "match is: $strFilename$strExtension and $strFilename2$strExtension2"
                } Else {
                    Write-Host "Not a match: $strFilename$strExtension and $strFilename2$strExtension2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help please?

Regards

Darren

Comment: This can be done. Have you tried anything in getting a solution yourself that we can help you with? SO is not a code writing service but a resource for helping programmers and programming enthusiasts.

Comment: I tried, got lost, went round and round in circles, too much code, arrays not working etc etc ended up pulling the pin as i'm not a programmer in any great sense and as soon as arrays come into im lost, so thought, im sure someone out there would know this in about 5mins

Comment: This is what I have so far but my match and not match are reversed?
Also, how do I add the other extension types in?

Comment: gewd - how do you add code in to SO ???

Comment: Use the `edit` link under the question, add your code, mark it all and then press the `{ }` button in the editor or press `Ctrl + K`

Comment: _(I think you can even delete the 2 comments above afterwards for clarity)_

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for including your code. You have the right idea of comparing names and and extensions but lets try a different approach.

We loop each file and check its extension. Depending on if the file is a trg file or not we have a similar mean to check for its partner. Since we use a `Where-Object` clause the output files are passed onto the pipe to `Remove-Item` for deletion. Test with the `-WhatIf` switch to verify it is working.

I tried to use simple cmdlets and methods for string manipulation.

```
$path = "C:\temp\test"
$extension = "_trg"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path
$fileNames = $files | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$files | Where-Object{
    # Check what extension this file is so we can find the appropriate partner
    if($_.Extension.Contains($extension)){
        # Attempt to find a matching non trg file
        $fileNames -notcontains $_.Name.Substring(0, $_.Name.LastIndexOf($extension))
    } else {
        # Attempt to find a matching trg file
        $fileNames -notcontains "$($_.Name)$extension"
    }
} | Remove-Item -Force -Confirm:$false -WhatIf
```

We save all the file names in `$fileNames` and use `-notcontains` to see if the file in the loop has its partner in the list. If not it passed through the pipe.